# add commas into number for output

Tags: r, xtable

I'm outputting a dataframe to html via `xtable`. I want to add commas to numbers in a couple columns of the table. I figured before I did my own paste hack I'd check if there is a built in way to do this.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You might want to consider transforming the column using `formatC`

```
> formatC(1:10 * 100000, format="d", big.mark=",")
 [1] "100,000"   "200,000"   "300,000"   "400,000"   "500,000"   "600,000"  
 [7] "700,000"   "800,000"   "900,000"   "1,000,000"
```

Comment: Do you know how to format an entire document like that?

Answer (score 17):

Huge thanks to Jonathan Chang for his answer. `formatC` looks to be an extremely useful function. This inspired me to read the documentation for it, wherein I found `prettyNum`, which turned out to be a pretty elegant solution to a similar problem I was having. Here's a minimum viable example of what I did to add commas to numbers in a data frame named `enrollment.summary`.

`xtable(prettyNum(enrollment.summary,big.mark=","))`

Comment: `formatC` is a [function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formatc.html) in the `base` package, not a package itself. In the future, please include reproducible examples and display the behavior in your answer. For example, consider replacing `enrollment.summary` with `mtcars`: `prettyNum(mtcars, big.mark=",")` returns a character matrix where columns correspond to columns in the `mtcars` data.frame, and numbers are printed.

Comment: Also note that `prettyNum` pads your output with (potentially unwanted) blank space: prettyNum(c(123,1234),big.mark=","); gives " 123" "1,234". add preserve.width="none" to prevent this.

Answer (score 14):

You can also try using the function argument 'format.args'

```
  ## Demonstration of additional formatC() arguments.
  print(fm1.table, format.args = list(big.mark = "'", decimal.mark = ","))
```

from here

https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/xtable/xtable.pdf

Comment: This is very useful, as it allows the user to keep the original format of the columns.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a late answer, but you could also use `scales::comma_format` as follows:

```
library(scales)
values <- c(1000000.789, 8888.23)
comma_format(digits = 12)(values)
## [1] "1,000,000.789" "8,888.230"
```

For just integer values, you can just use comma:

```
library(scales)
int_vals <- c(1234, 5678)
comma(int_vals)
## [1] "1,234" "5,678"
```

Comment: One thing which goes wrong for me is that it converts it to string

Comment: @SovikGupta Yes, it will. You only want to add the commas when you display it. If you have the data in a `data.frame` you would likely keep it as numeric. What is your circumstance where this is causing an issue ?

Comment: @SovikGupta An example using `dplyr` could either add a string version of the column as in `dplyr::tibble(A = c(1:5) * 1e6) %>% dplyr::mutate(A.as.String = scales::comma(A))` or just output as a string w/o modifying the data frame as in `dplyr::tibble(A = c(1:5) * 1e6) %>% dplyr::mutate(A = scales::comma(A))`

Answer (score 7):

to format some summaries from `dplyr`, here is boilerplate code:

```
df %>%
    summarise(mu=mean(big_values),
              min=min(big_values),
              max=max(big_values)) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(prettyNum(., big.mark=",")))
```